# Get the return URL from a JavaScript function and send it as a parameter to the action

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts2, struts

I have a JavaScript file: `informacoesImportantes.js` and in it I have a function that generates a destination URL to Whatsapp.

You need to get the URL and pass it as a parameter to a `qrCode.do` action, but apparently it's calling the `qrCode` even before generating the link, because it's always going empty, but when you open the browser console and print the variable, the link is there .

I'm trying to send a parameter to `Action`, but the parameter comes through a JavaScript function. I tried several ways with `<c:set>` or even directly call the `:javascript` after the parameter directly in the `src`, but without success.

**`informacoesImportantes.js`:**

```js
function gerarUrlWhatsapp(especialidade,data,hora,medico,unidadeMedica,enderecoCompleto) {

    var texto = "Seguem dados de confirma\u00e7\u00e3o do agendamento: "+"\n"+
    " Especialidade: "+especialidade+"\n"+
    " Data: "+data+"\n"+
    " Hora: "+hora+"\n"+
    " M\u00e9dico: "+medico+"\n"+
    " Unidade "+unidadeMedica+"\n"+
    " Endere\u00e7o: "+enderecoCompleto + "\n"+
    " Informa\u00e7\u00f5es importantes:" + "\n";
    
    return "https://wa.me/?text=" + texto;
}
```

**`agendamentoDetalhe.jsp`:**

```xhtml
<div class="col-sm-3 gnm-container-qrcode">
  <script>
      var urlWhats = gerarUrlWhatsapp('${ agendamento.especialidade.dsEspecialidade}','${dateParts[0]}','${dateParts[1]}','${agendamento.nomePrestador}','${agendamento.unidadeMedica.nome}','${agendamento.unidadeMedica.enderecoCompleto}');
  </script>
    <c:set var="qrCodeUrlWhatsapp" value="${urlWhats}" />
  <img src="../qrCode.do?qrCodeUrlWhatsapp=javascript:gerarUrlWhatsapp('${ agendamento.especialidade.dsEspecialidade}','${dateParts[0]}','${dateParts[1]}','${agendamento.nomePrestador}','${agendamento.unidadeMedica.nome}','${agendamento.unidadeMedica.enderecoCompleto}');"/>
    <p>${urlWhats}</p>
</div>
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
  <action name="qrCode" class="**" method="qrCode">
    <result name="success" type="stream">
      <param name="contentType">image/jpeg</param>
      <param name="inputName">qrCodeImage</param>
      <param name="bufferSize">4096</param>
    </result>
  </action>
```

**`AgendamentoAction.java`:**

```java
public String qrCode() {
  qrCodeImage = generateQrCodeImpl.createQrCode(accessToken, qrCodeUrlWhatsapp);
}
```

Comment: What is the action doing? Does it use JavaScript url to connect?

Comment: Yes, is action generation to qr code after init a page

Comment: JSP runs on the server side. JS runs on the client. You’re mixing the two; `urlWhats` is JS (client), and you’re attempting to set a JSP (server) custom table value with it. That isn’t how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a JavaScript function in the `<img src=`. But you can modify the value of the `src` attribute. If you add an `id` attribute to the `<img>` tag then you can get this element from the `document` using JavaScript and modify `src` attribute after calling a custom function.

The below script should be in the JSP file, so the EL expressions have being evaluated before the document is rendered.

```html
<img id="qrCodeId" src="#">
<script>
   var urlWhats = gerarUrlWhatsapp('${ agendamento.especialidade.dsEspecialidade}','${dateParts[0]}','${dateParts[1]}','${agendamento.nomePrestador}','${agendamento.unidadeMedica.nome}','${agendamento.unidadeMedica.enderecoCompleto}');
   document.getElementById("qrCodeId").src="../qrCode.do?qrCodeUrlWhatsapp="+encodeURIComponent(urlWhats);
</script>
```